# Ansible: Control User Requirements

Tags: automation, ansible

Being a new ansible user, I'm not able to understand if the control user (except root) needs to exist on target machines too or can those machine be controlled by any user on control machine?

I've tried to go through documentation, but is too overwhelming for a beginner. So tell me if below scenario can be possible?

- sudoUser1 exists on control machine but not on target machines? Or Do I have to create same user on control machine as well as target nodes?

Comment: Ansible (in the case of Linux target machines) simply uses SSH to connect. So the accounts that you use to connect to the targets and (optionally) then sudo to to run tasks, all need to exist on the target machine.

Comment: @clockworknet so I'm logged in on control machine as say named normaluser which doesn't exist on target targets, but I have a sudouser with same name on all targets, how would I use that user to control target machines? I mean where should I put id_rsa file on control machine? hence there's no homedir for that sudouser on control machine? I'm confused, see my point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a control node as a user (User1@controller) configure ssh connection to the target (User2@target). For example:

```
[User1@controler]# ssh-copy-id User2@target
```

Test SSH connection

```
[User1@controler]# ssh User2@target
```

On target allow User2 sudo

```
# grep User2 /usr/local/etc/sudoers
User2 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

On controller create inventory

```
[User1@controler]# cat hosts
target
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_user=User2
ansible_become=yes
ansible_become_user=root
ansible_become_method=sudo
```

Test Ansible

```
[User1@controler]# ansible -m setup target
```

Ansible is a flexible tool. There are many other variations how to configure it. YMMV.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, that does address what I was asking in particular, bless you.

Comment: btw, does it ask for password on second step? here >>> ([User1@controler]# ssh User2@target)....moreover I'm getting this error after I enter password >> (sh: .ssh/authorized_keys: Permission denied)

Comment: I got this error >> ( target | UNREACHABLE! => { "changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).\r\n", "unreachable": true } ) when I ran this >> ( ansible -m setup target )

Comment: No, 2nd step should not ask for password. Error "authorized_keys: Permission denied" is pretty clear, isn't it?

Comment: yea seemed like user wasn't owner. But I get errors when I run setup command.